# FB.logout() called without an access token. all.js:54

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, access-token, facebook-access-token

I load the facebook SDK like this:

```
(function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));
```

So, I get this error:

```
FB.logout() called without an access token. all.js:54
```

How would I fix this? as its in the facebook SKD file?!

Comment: all.js works with [v1.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v1.0) of the Facebook Graph API. You should use the [v2.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.0) instead. Also, what SDK call are you making which leads to this error message? The code you've shown only loads the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Full instruction can find [here](https://www.codexworld.com/login-with-facebook-using-javascript-sdk/)